# How to auto insert new values to JOIN table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm semi-new to SQL but as far as I know, the following scenario can be solved using triggers, I'm just not sure how.

I have created a `users_to_branches` table. It's a JOIN table - taking `users.id`, `users.name` from `users` table, and a `branch.name` from `branches` table. The tables are joined on `branch_ID` that both `users` and `branches` tables have.

Now, `users_to_branches` does not update, even if the new records are being inserted into `users` table. Is it possible to set up using triggers, so the `users.id`, `users.name` and `branch.name` will automatically be inserted as a new record in `users_to_branches`?

Comment: Huh?  I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: I want my JOIN table to be updated whenever a new record is inserted in one of the tables that is consists of. So in users_to_branches I want new records to appear just as a new record appears in users table.

Comment: How can it- branch is unknown when inserting to users??

Comment: branch_ID is a column in both, users and branches tables. So whenever user is added in users table, so is his branch_ID. However in users_to_branches I want to display the branch_name which only appears in branches table.

Comment: Hence the confusion I(we) would expect a joining/junction table to hold the many to many relationships and that the user table would not have a branch id, if it does then the junction table may be pointless also I would not expect branch_name to be stored in junction table - only id sample data and expected outcome would help clarify

Comment: I joined the tables for analysis purposes as I reckoned it will be the easiest way of creating reports (branch_name matters more than branch_id in our case), but what you're saying is that it's not necessary to JOIN the tables, and I could display branch_name, even if it's not available in the users table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't agree with your model but if you insist

```
drop table if exists t,t1,t_t1;
create table t(id int,branch_id int);
create table t1(id int,name varchar(3));
create table t_t1(uid int,branch_name varchar(3));

drop trigger if exists t;
delimiter $$
create trigger t after insert on t
for each row 
begin
    insert into t_t1(uid,branch_name)
    select new.id,name
    from   t1 branch;
end $$
delimiter ;
insert into t1 values(1,'aaa');
insert into t  values(1,1);

select * from t_t1;

+------+-------------+
| uid  | branch_name |
+------+-------------+
|    1 | aaa         |
+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm open for suggestions tho, how would you solve my problem? Is there a better way of data in my example without the JOIN?

Comment: You should review https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity which contains a couple of examples very similar to what you seem to want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert rows into `user_to_branches` using *names* rather than ids, you can use a query:

```
insert into user_to_branches (user_id, branch_id)
    select u.user_id, b.branch_id
    from users u join
         branches b
         on u.name = ? and b.name = ?;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't materialize that. That would make redundant data and redundant data may lead to inconsistencies.

Drop that *table* `users_to_branches` and the triggers. Instead you can create a *view* `users_to_branches` that does the join so that you don't have to repeatedly type that in your queries.

```
CREATE VIEW users_to_branches
SELECT u.id user_id,
       u.name user_name,
       b.name branch_name
       FROM users u
            LEFT JOIN branches b
                      ON b.branch_id = u.branch_id;
```